# How to get values from another running thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I am executing `itasser.run()` in my GUI class. But because it is a complete process itself, `publish(itasser.getTimeToFinish())` executes only after `itasser.run()`.

So is there a way I can use itasser.getTimeToFinish() or other values while `run()` completes?

I have many other objects like itasser that I'll be executing is same way and update GUI.

```
final ITasser itasser = new ITasser();
itasser.setInput(getString1(), getString1(), getString1());

SwingWorker<ProcessStatus, Integer> worker = 
    new SwingWorker<ProcessStatus, Integer>() 
{
    @Override
    protected ProcessStatus doInBackground() throws Exception {
        itasser.run(); //complete task

        publish(itasser.getTimeToFinish()); //??? problem
        //executes only after itasser.run() completes

        return itasser.getStatus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        // display remaining time on GUI
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        if(get() == ProcessStatus.FINISHED)
            itasser.getOutput(); //do something with output
    }
};

worker.execute();
```

Comment: Look at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

I would use BackgroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx to complete tasks in diffrent threads and then use deleggate for accessing values.

Comment: That is C#. I am asking about Java

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen tags!